# Convert UTC timestamp column but get ValueError: time data '-27' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Given a UTC timestamp column from dataframe, I want to convert them into format like `2018-10-07 06:59:05.162000`:

```
         _source.@timestamp
0  2018-10-07T06:59:05.162Z
1  2018-10-07T06:59:05.075Z
2  2018-10-07T06:59:05.103Z
3  2018-10-07T06:59:05.093Z
4  2018-10-07T06:59:05.108Z
5  2018-10-07T06:59:05.110Z
6  2018-10-07T06:59:07.148Z
7  2018-10-07T06:59:09.164Z
8  2018-10-07T06:59:09.214Z
```

I have applied the code below:

```
df['_source.@timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_source.@timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

But it raises an error: `ValueError: time data '-27' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ' (match)`

By adding `errors='coerce'`:

```
df['_source.@timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_source.@timestamp'], 
                                       format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', 
                                       errors='coerce')
```

I get the result below, but seems incorrect:

```
2018-10-07T06:59:05.162Z   NaT
2018-10-07T06:59:05.075Z   NaT
2018-10-07T06:59:05.103Z   NaT
2018-10-07T06:59:05.093Z   NaT
2018-10-07T06:59:05.108Z   NaT
                            ..
2018-10-07T09:55:33.596Z   NaT
2018-10-07T09:55:33.647Z   NaT
2018-10-07T09:55:33.581Z   NaT
2018-10-07T09:55:33.655Z   NaT
2018-10-07T09:55:35.593Z   NaT
Name: _source.@timestamp, Length: 10000, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This code may help to solve problem:

```
utc = "2018-10-07T06:59:05.162Z"
UTC_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
utcTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(utc, UTC_FORMAT)
print(utcTime)
```

Out:

```
2018-10-07 06:59:05.162000
```

How could I convert the column correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error, so just asking, have you tried without specifying the format like `pd.to_datetime(df['_source.@timestamp'])`?

Comment: For me working correct with sample data too.

Comment: sidenote: since you have ISO 8601 compatible strings, e.g. `pd.to_datetime('2018-10-07T06:59:05.162Z')` parses correctly to `Timestamp('2018-10-07 06:59:05.162000+0000', tz='UTC')`. So you don't *have* to provide a `format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column name `'_source.@timestamp'` makes python think its an email hyperlink and not a string, hence you are getting a keyError.

Do this instead -

```
df.iloc[:,0] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Output-

```
0   2018-10-07 06:59:05.162
1   2018-10-07 06:59:05.075
2   2018-10-07 06:59:05.103
3   2018-10-07 06:59:05.093
4   2018-10-07 06:59:05.108
5   2018-10-07 06:59:05.110
6   2018-10-07 06:59:07.148
7   2018-10-07 06:59:09.164
8   2018-10-07 06:59:09.214
Name: _source.@timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: For you not working `df['_source.@timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_source.@timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')` ?

Comment: Yes, I think the problem occured because of column's name, when I rename, no error any more.